# MAMP Pro - MySQL won't start after update from MAMP 3.x to 4.x

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

Good day all... Hope someone can assist. On first startup, after upgrading from MAMP 3.x to 4.1.1; MySQL won't start. I will attach the error log (which reads like Greek to me). Any ideas I can try out are appreciated.

```
    2017-03-07 13:28:39 8136 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-03-07 13:28:39 8136 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-03-07 13:28:39 8136 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-03-07 13:28:39 8136 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-03-07 13:28:39 8136 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-03-07 13:28:39 8136 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-03-07 13:28:39 8136 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-03-07 13:28:39 8136 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-03-07 13:28:39 8136 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-03-07 13:28:39 8136 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-03-07 13:28:46 8136 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-03-07 13:28:46 8136 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-03-07 13:28:46 8136 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.35 started; log sequence number 1056735100
2017-03-07 13:28:46 8136 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2017-03-07 13:28:46 8136 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2017-03-07 13:28:46 8136 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2017-03-07 13:28:46 8136 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2017-03-07 13:28:46 8136 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' cannot be opened.
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [Warning] Info table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' cannot be opened.
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.events_waits_current is wrong. Expected 19, found 16. Created with MySQL 50525, now running 50635. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.events_waits_history is wrong. Expected 19, found 16. Created with MySQL 50525, now running 50635. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.events_waits_history_long is wrong. Expected 19, found 16. Created with MySQL 50525, now running 50635. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_host_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name: expected column 'THREAD_ID' at position 0 to have type bigint(20), found type int(11).
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_user_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_account_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.file_summary_by_event_name is wrong. Expected 23, found 5. Created with MySQL 50525, now running 50635. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.file_summary_by_instance is wrong. Expected 25, found 6. Created with MySQL 50525, now running 50635. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'host_cache' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.mutex_instances: expected column 'LOCKED_BY_THREAD_ID' at position 2 to have type bigint(20), found type int(11).
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'objects_summary_global_by_type' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.rwlock_instances: expected column 'WRITE_LOCKED_BY_THREAD_ID' at position 2 to have type bigint(20), found type int(11).
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_actors' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_objects' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'table_io_waits_summary_by_table' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'table_lock_waits_summary_by_table' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.threads is wrong. Expected 14, found 3. Created with MySQL 50525, now running 50635. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_current' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_history' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_history_long' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_summary_by_user_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_summary_by_host_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_current' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_history' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_history_long' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_user_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_host_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_digest' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'users' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'accounts' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'hosts' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'socket_instances' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'socket_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'socket_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_connect_attrs' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_account_connect_attrs' has the wrong structure
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-03-07 13:28:47 8136 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.35'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```